Escaping single quotes for bulk insert into temp table, then copy to main
I have data frame with columns that may contain single quotes in the data. i am writing this table to a temp table, then selecting that into the real table to do an upsert (insert or on conflict, update).
This is what my sql to create the temp table in postgres looks like:
sql_create=f'drop table if exists tmp_tbl; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tbl ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT {cols} FROM {table_name} LIMIT 0;'

Before attempting the bulk insert i escape the data and i have confirmed after escaping, the data has double single quotes for places where there was single quotes.
Here is the code to insert the dataframe into the temp table:
try:
    with psycopg.connect(self.connect_str, autocommit=False) as conn:
        io_buf = io.StringIO()
        df.to_csv(io_buf, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
        io_buf.seek(0)

        with conn.cursor() as cur:
           cur.execute(sql_create)
           with cur.copy(sql_copy) as copy:
              while data:=io_buf.read(self.batch_size):
                 copy.write(data)

            cur.execute(sql_full)
            
except Exception as ex:
    self.log.error(ex)
    raise ex

(sql_full is does a select into the main table. it doesnt seem really relevant here since the data is ending up in the tmp table with the double single quotes.)
Im not sure its relevant either since i did mention i checked that the data is properly escaped by the time the copy begins, but here is the escape code:
   @staticmethod
   def escape_df(df):
      # for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
      #    df[col] = np.array([str(item).replace("'", "''") for item in df[col].values])
      # return df
      for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
         df[col] = np.where(df[col].str.contains("''"), 
                           df[col], 
                           df[col].str.replace("'", "''"))
      return df

This always seems to cause the data to end up in the postgres database as it appears in the dataframe (escaped with double quotes).
I have tried escaping with 4 single quotes, same thing.
i have tried using csv.QUOTE_NONE, csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, still the same.
anyone have any thoughts on how to solve this?


Do not use f strings, use the psycopg sql module to build properly escaped dynamic SQL. 2) Why are you doing escape_df in the first place? Not sure what the single quotes are supposed to be doing as all CSV data enters as text anyway.


it is unclear what you are asking, please give us enough code that we can easily replicate the problem.

@AdrianKlaver there are people names and company names that have single quote/apostrophes...some times users interchange one for the other.  im trying to avoid using psycopg/postrgres specific sql, in case we change databases or someone wants to use another database.

You are entering the realm of premature optimization. Don't start coding for situations you have not encountered or even know exist. I would say in this day and age any mature system dealing with data will know how to deal with a single quote/apostrophe.

thx.  it turns out after coming up with a slimmed down runnable example in jupytr, i discovered the issue wasnt inserts, but selects (i select the data after inserting).  there i need to do the escaping.  i have changed the select to use parameters instead of building the where with the values.
